# Sikuli UnsatisfiedLinkError when using sikuli-script.jar

Tags: java, python, sikuli

I'm on Windows 7 32bit, Java JRE6 31 installed and using Sikuli X 1.0rc3. I want to launch a test with sikuli-script.jar like this:

```
java -jar c:\sikuli\sikuli-script.jar test.sikuli
```

All I get is this error message:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:C:\sikuli\libs\VisionProxy.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
```

I have set all the environment variables needed, so my PATH looks like this:

```
PATH=...;C:\sikuli\libs;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin
SIKULI_HOME=C:\sikuli
```

I can use the IDE and launch the tests there etc. But only if I use the `Sikuli-IDE.exe` the `sikuli-ide.bat` and `sikuli-ide.jar` don't work either. Always with the same error from above. So I think in the build process of the .exe file they added some magic, but I can't figure out what it is.

Does somebody have a similar problem? Or even a solution?

---

### Update

As I wrote below, it works out of the box with my new computer. :D But maybe my solution can help someone.

Sikuli Team uses [Launch4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) to build the `Sikuli-IDE.exe` out of the `sikuli-ide.jar`. They use [this](https://github.com/sikuli/sikuli/blob/develop/sikuli-ide/l4j-conf.xml) config file. I modified it slightly and created a `Sikuli-script.exe`. It was pretty simple but I lost the config file unfortunately.

Hope I could help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You must use a 32bit JRE version (I use jre-7u4-windows-i586.exe)
2. Download Sikuli IDE for Windows (I use "Sikuli X r930", portable version)
3. Unpack it and copy files to your project folder (I renamed it to "sikuli-ide", check image htt+p://i.stack.imgur.com/LSiQV.png)
4. Add sikuli-script.jar to the Referenced Libraries (Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries, check image https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2SJ8.png)
5. Set PATH and SIKULI_HOME environment vars (Run > Run Configurations > Environment, check image https://i.stack.imgur.com/HboXk.png)
6. You're ready to go ;)

Answer (score 3):

According to the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError.html)

`Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine cannot find an appropriate native-language definition of a method declared native.`

What you need to do is use this command:

```
-Djava.library.path=pathToDLL
```

Which will add your DLL that is missing.

Comment: Or alternatively, move the DLL: `C:\sikuli\VisionProxy.dll` It's better to set the lib path, though.

Comment: That doesn't work... I found a solution with Launch4j, which I will post when I have the time.

Comment: I got a new computer at work, installed everything like the last time. But now it works... :D