# Exporting image in runnable jar doesn't work

Tags: java, image, file

I'm having a weird problem in java. I want to create a runnable jar:
This is my only class:

```
public class Launcher {

public Launcher() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String path = Launcher.class.getResource("/1.png").getFile();
    File f = new File(path);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,Boolean.toString(f.exists()));

}

}
```

As you can see it just outputs if it can find the file or not. **It works fine under eclipse** (returns true). i've created a source folder resources with the image 1.png. (resource folder is added to source in build path)

As soon as I export the project to a runnable jar and launch it, it returns false.
I don't know why. Somebody has an idea?
Thanks in advance

edit: I followed example 2 to create the resources folder: [Eclipse exported Runnable JAR not showing images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25635636/eclipse-exported-runnable-jar-not-showing-images)

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to load resources from your .jar file use `getClass().getResource()`. That returns a URL with correct path.

```
Image icon = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("image´s path"));
```

To access images in a jar, use `Class.getResource()`.

I typically do something like this:

```
InputStream stream = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("Icon.png");
if(stream == null) {
   throw new RuntimeException("Icon.png not found.");
}

try {
   return ImageIO.read(stream);
} catch (IOException e) {
   throw new RuntimeException(e);
} finally {
   try {
      stream.close();
   } catch(IOException e) { }
}
```

Still you're understand, Kindly go through this link.

[Eclipse exported Runnable JAR not showing images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25635636/eclipse-exported-runnable-jar-not-showing-images)

Comment: Thank you, what should I pass to "new File"? In order for the code to work?

Answer (score 0):

Because the image is not separate file but packed inside the .jar.

Use the code to create the image from stream

```
InputStream is=Launcher.class.getResourceAsStream("/1.png");
Image img=ImageIO.read(is);
```

Comment: And how do I get from the inputstream to file? In other words how do I see if the file exists?

Comment: the stream is not null

Comment: Yeah okay, but I'm using a function that expects the PATH to an image. i guess I can't pass the inputstream...

Comment: You just don't have the path. If you need a file create it from the stream, store somewhere and use the newly created file passing the path to your function. I would rather rewrite the function to use stream rathar than file.

Comment: It's a library sikuli, for image comparison. I'm not going to rewrite it. But if I do "this.getClass().getResource("/image").getPath()", I'll get the path right? And I can pass that to the method, or am I missing something?

Comment: The library have another ways to initialize by URL, image (and I guess by stream) E.g. by URL new ImageTarget(new URL("site/targetImage.png")) or by image BufferedImage bigImage = ImageIO.read(new File("targetImage.png"));
BufferedImage smallImage = bigImage.subImage(50,50,100,100);
Target target = new ImageTarget(smallImage); Yoou have to investigate. File is not only way

Comment: right now I'm using Pattern target=new Pattern(path); where path=this.getClass().getResource("/1.png").getPath(); It works in eclipse. But I've no idea if it will work when exported since I'm having a problem exporting the sikuli library: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27880151/exporting-an-app-with-sikuli As far as I can see there's only one constructor: http://doc.sikuli.org/pattern.html

Comment: At the end of this link : http://sikulix-2014.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq/030-java-dev.html#how-to-use-sikulix-api-in-your-java-programs-or-java-aware-scripting there's something about using images inside jar, but I've got no idea what they mean...

Answer (score 0):

try to use this to get image

```
InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/your image path in jar");
```

Answer (score 0):

Two Simple steps:

1 - Add the folder ( where the image is ) to Build Path;

2 - Use this:

```
InputStream url = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/load04.gif");
myImageView.setImage(new Image(url));
```