# Sikuli Trouble with ImagePath (JAVA)

Tags: java, image, maven, sikuli

I'm having a problem exporting a maven project in eclipse that uses the sikuli library. In eclipse everything works fine and the application runs great. I also have to note that I never used maven before (so I might do something "stupid"). The problem is that once exported, the application can't find the images I stored within the runnable jar. This is the error I got: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BymG7-nABOfnTmR0NzdTXzlSU2M/view

The images are stored in resources inside the sikuli map. You can see the code and project hierarchy over here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BymG7-nABOfnazJqYTg5ekJzSFE/view?usp=sharing

The main method is written inside Launcher.java. I think the problem in my code is located near the ImagePath.add line. Can anyone help me, so the application runs outside eclipse?

There is some information about ImagePath on these websites:
http://sikulix-2014.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq/030-java-dev.html
http://sikulix-2014.readthedocs.org/en/latest/scripting.html#imagesearchpath

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try removing the package, and just specify the Class?

Comment: Yes, if I do that, it won't even run in eclipse.

Comment: In the doc, they talk about this, where you can add an alternative path if you want to be able to run under Maven and from inside the IDE: _ImagePath.add("someClass/images", alternatePath)_

Comment: But that's not under "Usage in Maven Projects:", that's under "Usage in other Projects:". But anyways, I want to try it. How would that line of code look like if I use the alternate Path? Like this: ImagePath.add("Launcher/sikuli","application.Launcher/sikuli"); ?

Comment: Becuase if I try that line I get: [error] ImagePath: add: class Launcher not found on classpath.
[error] ImagePath: add: not valid: Launcher/sikuli  / application.Launcher/sikuli

Comment: Just had a look at the code, maybe try something like ImagePath.add("application.Launcher/sikuli","application.Launcher/sikuli");

Comment: So two time the same parameter? I get the error: [error] ImagePath: add: not valid: application.Launcher/sikuli  / application.Launcher/sikuli

Comment: You've got another idea what the problem could be? I've got this problem for over two weeks now :(

Comment: Have you solved that problem? I have the same :-(

Answer (score 1):

try this,

Import the following

```
 import org.sikuli.basics.ImageLocator;
```

use this function inside your program

```
ImageLocator.setBundlePath("path to img directory");
```