# How to create executable (.exe) file for any platform using Sikuli-script + Java + Eclips IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, sikuli

I have create `java application` using `sikuli-script(latest version 1.0.1)`.

I added the `sikuli-script.jar` to the `Referenced Libraries` (I configured using this answer [Answer Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10354722/2560448))

`java code` folder structure -->
[image]

`Java code` -->

```
package com.example.sikuli;

import org.sikuli.script.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;    

public class TestSikuli {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Screen s = new Screen();
            App app = new App("C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe");//firefox path
            try{
                    app.focus();
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
                    s.click("imgs/1391152193781.png", 0);//url bar image   
                    s.type(null, "http://www.google.lk", 0);  
                    s.click("imgs/1391152289812.png", 0);//click search image
            }
            catch(FindFailed e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

}
```

After that i set the the `Run Configutrtion` such as `PATH` and `SIKULI_HOME`
[image]

Next I run the code it's working properly.

Then I create `.exe` using `launch4j` and according to this site instructions --> [How to Create an Executable File from Eclipse](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-an-Executable-File-from-Eclipse)

After that i run the `.exe` file from `command prompt` then following errors occurred. Please help me.

`Error` -->

```
[error] ResourceLoaderBasic: check: libs dir is empty, has wrong content or is outdated

[action] ResourceLoaderBasic: check: Please wait! Trying to extract libs to: C:\Documents and Settings\Dell\SikuliX\libs

[error] ResourceLoaderBasic: loadLib: Fatal Error 109: not found: C:\Documents and Settings\Dell\SikuliX\libs\VisionProxy.dll

[error] Terminating SikuliX after a fatal error(109)! Sorry, but it makes no sense to continue!

If you do not have any idea about the error cause or solution, run againwith a Debug level of 3. You might paste the output to the Q&A board.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

--1. when programming in Java using Sikuli, you should always use sikuli-java.jar (sikuli-ide.jar contains much stuff not needed here).

--2. Set a JVM option -Dsikuli.Debug=3 when running the exe to get more details about what's going on. I guess the problem is, that for some reason the export of the native libs does not work in the context of a launch4J exe (I did not test this yet).

--3. always use the latest version (1.1.1 in this case, still nightly but pre-final ;-) http://sikulix.com

Comment: I modified that your are mention in above answer but still problem. please help how can i create the (.exe) file.

Comment: I'm using Sikuli through Maven. I didn't do the Sikuli Setup for sikuli-java.jar file. While running the sikuli code in the server, I got the path not found error with the suggestion of restarting the machine. It is a server, i cant do the restart operation. Do we have any way to avoid restart operation to fix those errors.