# UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files (x86)\Sikuli X\libs\VisionProxy.dll: Can't find dependent libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, windows-7-x64, sikuli

I am just running sample sikuli script in Java on Eclipse & I am getting the following error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files (x86)\Sikuli X\libs\VisionProxy.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1807)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1703)
>       at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:770)
>       at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1003)
>       at com.wapmx.nativeutils.jniloader.NativeLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLoader.java:44)
>       at org.sikuli.script.Finder.(Finder.java:33)
>       at org.sikuli.script.Region.doFind(Region.java:1034)
>       at org.sikuli.script.Region$RepeatableFind.run(Region.java:1237)
>       at org.sikuli.script.Region$Repeatable.repeat(Region.java:1208)
>       at org.sikuli.script.Region.exists(Region.java:539)
>       at com.testsikuli.SikuliTest.main(SikuliTest.java:25)

```
public class SikuliTest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FindFailed {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "F:\\Softwares\\Selenium\\driver\\IEDriverServer.exe");
    WebDriver driver;
    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    Pattern userName = new Pattern("img/UserName.png");
    Screen sr = new Screen();
    sr.find(userName);
    sr.type(Key.ENTER);
    sr.type(Key.DELETE);
    sr.type("test");

}
```

}

I'd followed lot of post & tired ..no luck..

My system environment details,

1. 64bit Windows 7 SP1,
2. Java 6 (32bit) & eclipse JUNO (32bit)
3. Added JAVA_HOME = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\" & path =
   %JAVA_HOME%bin;%JAVA_HOME%jre\bin;
4. Also added SIKULI_HOME = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Sikuli X\" & path = %SIKULI_HOME%libs;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. I had followed the same steps in the following post

[Sikuli Windows 7 64 bit : Getting the VisionProxy.dll: Can not find dependent libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568612/sikuli-windows-7-64-bit-getting-the-visionproxy-dll-can-not-find-dependent-li)

and modified/selected only "Append environment to native environment" & now its working fine. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Was the Sikuli installation moved after it was installed at any time?  If using Sikuli X, all required dependencies should be included in the installation.

Make sure your IDE isn't picking up any 64-bit JRE files from somewhere, as this will cause the exact error you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

This user seems to have had the same problem. 
Maybe you can try this solution post: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403788/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-no-dll-in-java-library-path)

Same error reported at the Sikuli buglist. 
 
Java 7 does work for me though. 
[Link](https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/204875)

Comment: so do I need to change native library path to sikuli X/libs?

Comment: I think so. 
Because the file "VisionProxy.dll" is in the Sikuli directory "libs". 
Also check if that file realy exists, Sikuli 1.0.1 has some issues on updating that directory.

Comment: You could also try to remove the "libs" directory one time. That is my solution somethimes when I put setings on. (Since it won't update on its own.)

Comment: Thanks Tenzin. I tried to change native path that time also got same problem.