# Sikuli Java Code: ResourceLoaderBasic: loadLib: Fatal Error 110: loading: WinUtil.dll

Tags: java, intellij-idea, sikuli, sikuli-script

Here is my simple Sikuli java code:

```
import org.sikuli.script.App;
import org.sikuli.script.FindFailed;
/**
 * Created by Ripon on 5/19/2015.
 */
public class Calculator {
    public static void main(String... args)throws FindFailed, InterruptedException{
        App.open("calc.exe");
    }
}
```

When I ran, the following error message was shown in IntelliJ IDEA:

"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\bin\java" -Didea.launcher.port=7533 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\jre\lib\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;D:\Sikuli\MySikuliProject1\out\production\MySikuliProject1;D:\Sikuli\SikuliInstaller\sikuli-ide.jar;D:\Sikuli\SikuliInstaller\sikuli-java.jar;D:\Sikuli\SikuliInstaller\sikuli-setup.jar;D:\Sikuli\SikuliInstaller\sikuli-tessdata.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.2\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain misc.Calculator
[error] ResourceLoaderBasic: loadLib: Fatal Error 110: loading: WinUtil.dll
[error] ResourceLoaderBasic: loadLib: Since native library was found, it might be a problem with needed dependent libraries
D:\Sikuli\SikuliInstaller\libs\WinUtil.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
[error] ResourceLoaderBasic: loadLib: Check, wether a valid Sikuli libs folder is in system path at runtime!
[error] Terminating SikuliX after a fatal error(110)! Sorry, but it makes no sense to continue!
If you do not have any idea about the error cause or solution, run again
with a Debug level of 3. You might paste the output to the Q&A board.

Process finished with exit code 1

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A WinUtil.dll file is a file from the Sikuli library. 
Try deleting your `libs` folder, and then start your own script again.

Edit:

If this didn't work then a Java/Sikuli path might not be correctly setup. 
This first answer post (with the screenshots) might help in setting the path's correctly. 
 
There have been multiple people on this site with .dll files that could not be found, and this one seems to to the trick in many cases. 
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568612/sikuli-windows-7-64-bit-getting-the-visionproxy-dll-can-not-find-dependent-li)

Comment: [error] ResourceLoaderBasic: check: No valid libs path available until now!
[action] ResourceLoaderBasic: check: Please wait! Trying to extract libs to jar parent folder: D:/Sikuli/SikuliInstaller/
[error] ResourceLoaderBasic: loadLib: Fatal Error 110: loading: WinUtil.dll
[error] ResourceLoaderBasic: loadLib: Since native library was found, it might be a problem with needed dependent libraries
D:\Sikuli\SikuliInstaller\libs\WinUtil.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
[error] ResourceLoaderBasic: loadLib: Check, wether a valid Sikuli libs folder is in system path at runtime!

Comment: After deleting libs file I executed my script, the error message mentioned above was shown

Comment: Made an edit that might work for you. It is about a path that is not set correctly.

Comment: OS is Windows 7. User variable is set as PATH = D:\SikuliInstaller\libs; Nothing is there for System variables. Is it required? If yes, How to set System variable for Sikuli?

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.2